# Terminate event in PHP , can i call function when i terminate php

Tags: php

so basically i have a script that wont exit when i click "terminate" or stop in Eclipse Zend Studio so i thought if there was an event that fires once terminate buttom is pressed it could solve this problem.

So is there an event or hook that executes once i press on stop button ? anybody knows please?

I tried the following but it does not work.

```
function onDie(){
    $message = ob_get_contents(); // Capture 'Doh'
    ob_end_clean(); // Cleans output buffer

}
register_shutdown_function('onDie');
```

So any help please help!